# How to deploy SQL Function to target SQL Server 2016 database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I've looked all over for guides, but can't seem to find one that suits what I'm doing. I'm trying to follow the Pluralsight T-SQL by Dan Sullivan, and in his demonstration, when he creates a new SQL project, it asks for a target database. It does not so this for me in the newer VS 2017 environment.

I want to write a few C# functions and deploy them for use in a target, local database.

I've already scoured around for guides, and couldn't quite find a specific solution. I have imported the Database. When I click on Build->Deploy, it does nothing. If I hit F5, it says it's deploying, but I see nothing in the target database. I know basic SQL and connection strings already. I have downloaded SQL Server and SSMS, and I have the SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString SomeFunctions()
    {
        // Put your code here
        return new SqlString("Wassap?");
    }
}
```

All I want is to have my functions written in VS2017 to be accessible through T-SQL.

Comment: You need to first install an instance of SQL Server, be it any version. Then, the kind of ""prompt"" you are looking for requires a Visual Studio extension. If i recall correctly, that is "Sql Server Data Tools For Visual Studio". And if you have downloaded a database manager like SQL Server Management Studio, you won't need that. I suggest you to learn about basic SQL first, like sql connection string, data-providers in .Net etc. You don't need to go with T-Sql right now. Just start with the basics.

Comment: I know basic sql and connection strings already. I have downloaded SQL Server and SSMS, and I have the SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio. I always seem to have what I need but see completely different results that other people./

Comment: Your code is doing nothing. What do you actually expect ?

Comment: Well, the code is just a sample to see if it works at all. The idea is that I should be able to call that function and get 'Wassap?' as a return string. Issue has been solved now, I needed to know what Publish... did apparently.

Comment: Though it made no sense at all, i would still ask, what function are you talking about? The function in your code needs to be called to return the value. Plus, i don't see anything related to database or even SQL server here. The only relevant thing is the `SQLFuntion` attribute, which again, makes no sense.

Comment: I've figured it out. I can now Publish this function to my target database. Then, in the database, I can execute:

select dbo.SomeFunctions();

And get as a result: 'Wassap?'. This is now functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/841439/Create-Run-Debug-and-Deploy-SQL-CLR-Function-with

Turns out I was missing the Publish... functionality. Nothing else mentioned it that I could find aside from this guide. Good to know.